# Materialize CSS - Sidenav overlay covers all the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I am using Materialize css and I want to turn the navigation bar to sidenav in middle and small screens. I did it just like in the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#!). The problem is that when I click the menu button, sidenav is opened but it is like the image below

[image: sidenav]

I am not able to click the links in the sidenav since the sidenav-overlay covers all the page even the sidenav itself. It is closing when I try to click a link. Any suggestions how to solve it?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="">
        <div class="nav-wrapper red lighten-1">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png">
                </a>
                <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-sidenav" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                    <li><a href="#">How It Works?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
                    <li><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn deep-orange">Request Demo</button></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-sidenav">
                    <li><a href="#">How It Works?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
                    <li><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn deep-orange">Request Demo</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**I realized that the navbar-fixed have `z-index` of 997 (where sidenav-overlay is also 997), and I think it may cause the problem. However, side-nav have fixed positioning and `z-index` of 999. Is it dependent to its parent even if it has fixed position?**

Edit: I can solve it with changing the `left` property of sidenav-overlay, but I don't want to set it manually. I am looking for another solution.

Comment: do you  post some codes?

Comment: please create a demo with jsfiddle or codepen to better help you

Comment: Very likely to be caused by `z-index`. By default, the navigation `ul` should have `z-index: 999;` while `#sidenav-overlay` is `z-index: 997;`. Make sure you aren't overriding the `z-index` property with your own.

Comment: @josephting I didn't override any z-index property.

Comment: @josephting I checked it again from the browser, it shows `z-index` 999 for side-nav and 997 for sidenav-overlay.

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül Problem can't be solved if it isn't identified properly. There isn't enough information to identify the cause of the problem here.

Comment: I got same issue and fix it using #sidenav-overlay {  z-index: 996 !important; }, not sure if it has another side effects so far

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Because `<ul class="side-nav">` is contained within `<div class="navbar-fixed">` *and*  the overlay has the same z-index, you will always have this problem when using `navbar-fixed`.

You can mess around with the z-indexes of the various elements, but they each result in less than ideal displays when the side-nav is activated.

To work around this, I put `<ul class="side-nav">` parallel in the document structure to `<div class="navbar-fixed">` and the problem resolved itself.  Like this:

```
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-sidenav">
  <li><a href="#">How It Works?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
  <li><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn deep-orange">Request Demo</button></li>
</ul>
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="">
    <div class="nav-wrapper red lighten-1">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
          <img src="img/logo.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-sidenav" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="#">How It Works?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
          <li><button class="waves-effect waves-light btn deep-orange">Request Demo</button></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I did it the same way but forgot to answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: Still works in April 2020. EDIT: on page changes the overlay persists with an SPA..

Answer (score 1):

Modify the materialize CSS file to change the `#sidenav-overlay` to

```
#sidenav-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 120vh;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 996;
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the materialize CSS file to change the z-index in `#sidenav-overlay` to be 990. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the fix is far easier than messing with any z-index.  Simply make sure that your actual

```
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-sidenav">
```

content is **outside** of the `<header></header>` tags.  If it's inside the header tags, you will see the same behavior you posted here.

In my opinion this is the fault of the otherwise-great Materialize documentation.  They do make clear that the sidenav HTML should not be contained within the `<nav></nav>` tags, but don't indicate it won't work inside of the header tags.

**In sum**, your trigger needs to be within the `<nav></nav>` tags, and your actual sidenav content defined after the end of `</header>`.  This is better than fiddling with z-index as that could break other things down the line and becomes a maintenance headache.

[image]