# Materialize side-nav links doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm making an web with materializecss but links I add on the side nav doesn't work what can I do with it,

When I click the link the side-nav close
**code:**

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <a href="index.php" class="brand-logo left thin" title="bcgraphixx">Page Title</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="about-us.php">About us</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="book.php">booking</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                <li>
                    <div class="userView">
                        <div class="background">
                            <img src="<?php echo $srcurl; ?>/cover.png">
                        </div>
                        <a href="#!admin"><img class="circle" src="<?php echo $srcurl; ?>/logo.png"></a>
                        <a href="#!bcgraphix" title="bcgraphixTemplate"><span class="black-text name">DIGINEWS</span></a>

                    </div>
                </li>

                <li><a href="##"><center>MENU</center></a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="about-us.php">About us</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="book.php">booking</a></li>
            </ul>

            <script>  $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); </script>
        </div>

    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Post how it was solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrap your JS code for sideNav within `documentReady` event, and set parameter `closeOnClick` as `true`.
2. Bring your side menu (ul element with class"side-nav") at the same level of div with class `navbar-fixed` . This is to avoid known issues with overlay. See [this stackoverflow question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927744/materialize-css-sidenav-overlay-covers-all-the-page)

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
$('.button-collapse').sideNav({
      closeOnClick: true
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo right thin" title="bcgraphixx">Page Title</a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#">About us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
   <li><a href="##"><center>MENU</center></a></li>
   <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply code below....
you need to add CDN of materialize sc,js and jquery js
**Here is your fix nav bar**

```
      <div class="navbar-fixed">
        <nav class="nav-wrapper">
          <div class="container">
            <a href="" class="brand-logo">Picnic.lk</a>
            <a href="" class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-menu">
              <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
            </a>
            <ul class="hide-on-med-and-down right">
              <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
           </div>
         </nav>
       </div>
```

**your mobile nav bar (side nav)**

```
<ul class="sidenav grey lighten-2" id="mobile-menu">
    <li><a class="sidenav-close" href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a class="sidenav-close" href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="sidenav-close" href="#contact">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Add below js code**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //side navigation
    $('.sidenav').sidenav({
        //your additional code goes here
    });
 });
```